# What is the meaning of the 'Personalities' feature under /proc/mdstat

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

On some systems I see this :

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      10485696 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      477371328 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

And other systems show :

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      204788 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      4193272 blocks super 1.1 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      483985276 blocks super 1.1 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

I wonder what is the meaning of *Personalities* and the impact of having *different* values.

Comment: It's pretty much meaningless because they are typically loaded as modules, so you'll basically see what is it use at the moment. (or everything ever supported, as you see above)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [personalities](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat) are the RAID Levels that are supported by your Kernel. Your first example includes the [faulty] personality which can be used for diagnostic purposes. In Your second example the kernel (currently) only supports mirroring [raid1]